# Error dataTables con jQuery y Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, datatables

Estoy tratando de hacer lo siguiente utilizando dataTables. Lo que quiero es que aparezca en la primer columna el circulo con el más y que al dar clic despliegue los demás datos, como se muestra en la imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy siguiendo los pasos del ejemplo de dateTables que dejo en el siguiente link. https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/styling/bootstrap.html

Tengo referenciado todas estas librerías pero no me muestra el circulo con el más.

```js
<link rel="stylesheet" href="res/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"> <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/datatables/responsive.bootstrap.min.css">

<script type="" src="plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="res/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> <!-- datepicker -->
<script type="" src="plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="" src="plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="" src="plugins/datatables/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script type="" src="plugins/datatables/responsive.bootstrap.min.js"></script>


//El JavaScript

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
} );
</script>
```

**Alguien me puede decir que me hace falta o que tengo mal.**

Comment: ya revisaste la consola del navegador, para ver si hay algún recurso que no se este cargando por ejemplo, o si hay algún error en la ejecución de algún archivo?

Comment: Ya revise y no hay problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar directamente los **cdn** de las librerias, aunque si es exclusivamente en local, te recomiendo verificar si cada una de ellas funciona, también asegúrate de usar las siguientes clases en tu `table`

```
class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap"
```

Otro punto es que también tengas un número grande de columnas, ya que si es responsivo, en una pantalla grande no aparecerá el **+**, pero si es pequeña podrá aparecer.

Aqui un ejemplo usando los **cdn**:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.1/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.1/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.1/js/responsive.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- ojo con las clases -->
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>E-mail</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger</td>
                <td>Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
                <td>5421</td>
                <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett</td>
                <td>Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
                <td>8422</td>
                <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>
```

Comment: el código que colocaste me funciona, pero tengo una duda. Cree una carpeta donde guarde todas las librerías que descargue pero de ese modo no aparece el '+' la única forma para que aparezca el '+' y funcione es agregar las librerías directamente de la web, pero quiero descargarlas y referenciarlas y no me funciona que puede ser?  y que diferencia hay entre el class que colocas al inicio de tu respuesta y el class que colocas cuando haces la tabla. Gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Puedes hacer esto, entra a cada url que esta arriba y guarda los js o los css en otra carpeta y referencialos. No hay ninguna diferencia entre las dos class solo debes agregarlo al table

Comment: Excelente funcionó

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="" src="plugins/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="" src="plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="" src="plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="" src="plugins/datatables/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script type="" src="plugins/datatables/responsive.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Ponlos en ese orden de preferencia los JS hasta abajo, e intenta poner Jquery 1.12.4